# Missing classes in JaCoCo execution data for IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco, intellij-plugin

We are developing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA using Gradle with the official [Gradle IntelliJ Plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) as build tool.

We have written user interface tests using the [IntelliJ UI Test Robot](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-ui-test-robot) as suggested by the [official documentation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/testing-plugins.html#ui-tests). These UI tests are run by first running gradle task `runIdeForUiTests` in the background (starting the IDE in a way which allows it to be controlled remotely) and then running the `test` task to remotely control the IDE in an automated way in order to verify its behavior:

```
$ ./gradlew runIdeForUiTests &
$ ./gradlew test
```

Now we want to measure the coverage using [JaCoCo](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/). This happens mostly by itself for the `test` task, but we would like to include the `runIdeForUiTests` task, so that the coverage of the UI classes is measured as well. For this, the `build.gradle` file has been adjusted as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '1.2.1'
    id 'java'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.6.10"
    id 'jacoco'
}

// ...

group 'my.package'

// ...

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

// ...

jacoco {
    applyTo runIdeForUiTests
}

test {
    jacoco {
        includes = ['my.package.*']
    }
}

runIdeForUiTests {
    jacoco {
        includes = ['my.package.*']
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    getExecutionData().setFrom(fileTree(buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec"))
    reports {
        csv.required = true
        html.required = true
        xml.required = false
    }

}
```

The issue here is that no execution data is generated for the classes of the plugin, i.e. the `runIdeForUiTests.exec` file remains empty. If I [dump](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension.html#org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension:classDumpDir) the classes of the classpath (and comment out the [`includes`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension.html#org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension:includes) setting), only classes by Java, IntelliJ etc. appear there (and also in `runIdeForUiTests.exec`), though classes of the package `my.package` do not:

```
$ find build/jacoco/classpathdumps -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/jdk/nio/zipfs
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/jdk/internal/jimage
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/jdk/internal/jrtfs
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/jdk/nashorn/internal
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/jdk/nashorn/api
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/kotlin/script/experimental
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/jetbrains/cef
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/sun/jdi
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/sun/jndi
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/sun/tools
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/sun/security
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/intellij/util
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/intellij/concurrency
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/intellij/lang
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/intellij/ide
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/intellij/openapi
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/com/intellij/idea
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/javax/lang/model
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/sun/util/resources
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/sun/nio/cs
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/sun/security/pkcs11
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/sun/security/jgss
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/sun/security/smartcardio
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/sun/security/ec
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/org/jetbrains/kotlin
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/org/cef/handler
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/org/cef/callback
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/org/jcp/xml
build/jacoco/classpathdumps/org/w3c/dom
```

**How can we include the classes of our plugin in the coverage?**

I have read that mocking frameworks cause certain classes to be excluded, however we do not use such a framework so this cannot be the issue. I feel like it could be due to the plugin's classes being dynamically loaded by IntelliJ at runtime. I'm not sure though whether this is the case at all, and haven't been able to find out anything about this regarding JaCoCo.